# Working with _id representation as $oid in react js

Tags: mongodb

I have a web app working with React JS + ASP.NET MVC + MongoDB . MongoDB stores unique identifiers as _id in ObjectId format. The server sends back data in format:

```
{
_id : { $oid : "hw8hha88d8g8aas" },
otherdata : 123 ,
child : { _id : { $oid : "another id " } ,
         otherdata : 567 }
}
```

Now i am having difficulty converting this _id.$oid representation back into ObjectId before replacing the data in the document. Any ideas how I can efficiently manage this without having to modify all sub-documents?

The document is not too big but does need to hold few subdocuments.